# Invoke Apex Class Method from Account Page

Tags: apex, javascript, rest-api, visualforce-component, account

I have a class method that reinstalls a closed account. I need to create a button on the `Account` page that calls this method.

I have my class called `ClosedAccountMethods` implemented as such:

```
public class ClosedAccountMethods {
    public static void Reopen(string accId) {
        //Do all the reopen logic here
    }
}
```

I have tried a few different methods to be able to call this class from an `Account` page, but to no avail.

The first method was to modify `ClosedAccountMethods.Reopen()` into a REST endpoint, and then invoke it via a GET request from the `Account` page, but this caused an `INVALID_SESSION_ID` error that I don't know how to work around.

Next, I tried turning the button into an `OnClick Javascript` function, but it apparently isn't supported in Lightning, and so that doesn't seem feasible.

Lastly, I looked at creating a VisualForce component for the button to link to, but I don't have any experience with creating VF components, and at that point, it seemed like it was getting to complicated.

Is there any simple way to do this? Ideally, I just want a button on the Account page that allows the user to send a string into an Apex class method, that's all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Lightning" way is to use a simple quick action, in just a few simple steps.

## Step 1: Modify your Apex

You need to make it accessible to Lightning:

```
@AuraEnabled public static void Reopen(string accId) {
```

## Step 2: Build a Quick Action Component

Next, you need a Aura component:

## cmp

```
<aura:component controller="ClosedAccountMethods" implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWIthoutHeader">
  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.init}" value="{!this}" />
  <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Working..." />
</aura:component>
```

## Controller.js

```
({
  init: function(c, e, h) {
    let action = c.get("c.Reopen");
    action.setParams({accId:c.get("v.recordId")});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      // Handle errors here if you want //
      $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
})
```

## Step 3: Configure the Quick Action

Go to Setup > Object Manager > Accounts > Quick Actions, create a new quick action using this component.

## Step 4: Add to Page Layout

Finally, [add this to the page layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_add_actions_to_page_layout_lex.htm&type=5), and you're done.

Note that all of this above (except Apex) is case sensitive, so be careful when entering everything in, and you should be fine. You may want to read the Lightning Component Developer Guide for more information on what's going on, but once you've gotten this far, it's a pretty easy copy-paste design in case you need to use it elsewhere.

Comment: This was absolutely perfect. Thank you!